# What's official way to merge develop into master on Github?

Tags: git, github

I have a `master` branch and a `develop` branch. My `master` branch is the code that runs in production, and `develop` runs in the development environment. Several feature branches have been merged into `develop`. Now I'm trying to merge my `develop` branch into `master`. Here is my current process:

- I go to the PR page of Github: https://github.com/my_org/my_repo/pulls
- I click on New Pull Request
- I set my `develop` branch to merge into my `master` branch.

But when I look at the PR, it shows lots of old commits that are already in `master`. I also sometimes have to deal with merge conflicts that don't make sense (like the version number increments by one, but for some reason I get a merge conflict). After I merge, everything looks fine, but it makes me think I'm not doing it right. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: On the previous merges of stuff that you say is already in `master`, did you do _real_ merges, squashes or rebases?

Answer (score 1):

I bet you are not creating *real* merges when you are merging stuff into `master`. Let me explain a little bit. Suppose you have these branches:

```
*   third commit in master (master)
| * third commit in develop (develop)
| * another commit in develop
| * a commit in develop
* | another commit in master
* | a commit in master
|/
* initial commit
```

And let's say that we merge (a real merge) `develop` into `master`:

```
* Merge develop into master (master)
|\
* | third commit in master
| * third commit in develop (develop)
| * another commit in develop
| * a commit in develop
* | another commit in master
* | a commit in master
|/
* initial commit
```

Now suppose that some more work is done in `develop`:

```
*   Something else in master (master)
| * 5th commit in develop (develop)
| * 4th commit in develop
* | Merge develop into master
|\|
* | third commit in master
| * third commit in develop
| * another commit in develop
| * a commit in develop
* | another commit in master
* | a commit in master
|/
* initial commit
```

If you asked git to merge `develop` into `master`, git needs to look for (roughly) their *latest* common ancestor.... what is the latest commit that is present in both branches? `third commit in develop`, right? And so, all git needs to consider to do the merge is this tree:

```
*   Something else in master (master)
| * 5th commit in develop (develop)
| * 4th commit in develop
* | Merge develop into master
 \|
  * third commit in develop
```

But what happens if you did *squashes* instead when merging? Let's see the result of the *first* merge if you had squashed:

```
* Merge develop into master (master)
*   third commit in master
| * third commit in develop (develop)
| * another commit in develop
| * a commit in develop
* | another commit in master
* | a commit in master
|/
* initial commit
```

The trees are *almost* the same between the first merge with a real merge and this one with a squash... *but* you can see that, unlike the first merge, there is **no** relation between the (supposedly) merge commit and the source branch (`develop`)... and this is a deal breaker because, even if the `develop` branch does *not* move, if you tried to merge again, can you see what is the **latest** common ancestor? That is why you are still seeing commits that have been merged in the new PRs.

Bottom line: when merging stuff into `master`, *do not squash*, unless you know what you are doing.

The rule of thumb is that you *do not* squash if you are merging long-running branches. A feature branch that will die right at the moment that you merge is ok to be squash-merged.